# Is the length of folder names used when storing images on a site worth worrying about?

Tags: html, css, optimization

When I'm building a site, I always call the images folder (for inline or css) 'img'.
On a job, we're using the name 'images' which is fine by me.
It makes me curious about what people consider best practice though.

I see it like this:

**/img/**

1. Quick to type
2. Analagous to the `<img>` tag
3. Uses *slightly* less bits

**/images/**

1. Completely unambiguous. Clearly it contains images.

Am I crazy to even spend time thinking about this, or is there a recommended standard for naming this folder.

Comment: I would go for clarity but not let the total path length get over 256 characters.

Comment: @Jeroen What's the deal with 256 characters?

Comment: I guess even less. Since the relative path has to resolve to a physical path and i don't know what OS the site is running on you could get into trouble exceeded OS FileSystem limits right? And since a relative path is only a part of the absolute path i guess 256 is already too much. I would keep it as short as possible.

Comment: Apart from the problem with some Windows APIs and paths that are longer than `MAX_PATH` (which hasn't been a true limit as long as we had NTFS) there's really absolutely no reason to worry about 3 letters - that's the mother of all premature optimizations if I've ever seen one. Especially since depending on where you use it, you may not save anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably crazy to worry about this:

- In terms of data transfer the difference is negligible.
- In terms of SEO, Google knows an image is an image.
- In terms of development speed I imagine again the difference in time to type is also negligible.
- In terms of clarity, either "img" or "images" makes it pretty clear to a developer what's in here.
- And as far as I know there is no "standard" for this.

Answer (score 1):

For resources, like images used in CSS I always use **/img/** but for images that need to be stored or retrieved like Product images for example, then those go in **/images/** of course with more detailed folders inside.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always using /images/.

Don't know why you're thinking about this. I don't think it's bad to use /img/ instead of /images/. I'm used to use /images/.

And yes, /img/ uses slightly less bits than /images/. But if you have to worry about those bits...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a particular important issue, but to me, a well formatted and explicative URL is always better.

So I vote for "images" over "img".

A better descriptive word would be even better, for example if you have only images about a particular subject.

Comment: Is there really any developer out there that wouldn't instantly think of "images" if he read "img" in a resources folder? Hard to imagine imo

Comment: @Voo: URLs are not for developers only.

Comment: If "ordinary" people have to look at your urls to understand what's going on, I'd be more worried about the general UI design. And image urls are usually hidden from the view anyhow - I mean there's no reason to use "img" over "images" either. But I think generally the two are a wash (obviously if the URL is an important part of the UI it's worth thinking about, but that seems like a flawed design to begin with?)

Comment: @Voo: I think URLs are an important part of your website, also for navigation. I often use them like a time machine, to move between years or months. Since URLs represent resources, they must describe it correctly, without random characters or unclear words. It really doesn't matter in this example, but even that, I would stick with a clear word as a matter of principle.

Comment: I think it comes down to WHOM we think the resource is intended for. I think we all agree that for a programmer img is perfectly fine. So the question is basically do we think that the average visitor (someone who's actively looking for it, will almost certainly fall into the "programmer" category) of a homepage will or should ever get in contact with the path or interact with it in any way. Now I don't think they generally should, but I can see how that is open to discussion

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the img name for the images folder for the reasons that you outlined:

- Quick to type
- Uses slightly less bits

Instead /images/ provides users with easier to understand localization of resources on your website. So it is a little bit more user friendly ( it is good for SEO as well).

Anyway the differences are very small and if you use one instead of another you will not get visible improvements, so you do not have to worry about it.